# close modal box on escape key in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a modal box & i have used "modal-window.min.js".

I want to close modal box on escape key. For that I have written this code

```
document.getElementById('email').focus();
    jQuery(document).keydown(
        function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 27){            
            parent.jQuery.modal().close();      
        }
        }
        );
```

This code is working on firefox & IE but does not work in chrome.

Please give me a solution that works on all browsers. If anybody have solution trough "modal-window.min.js" file it will be better.

Thanks

Comment: If you are working wil `Dialogs` from jQueryUI they should automatically close on `ESC`. What Modal do you use? Some specs?

Comment: simple modal box...not a modal dialog box

http://www.techmodi.com/demo/yabblo/  goto login tab you will see the modal box

Comment: @MihaiIorga: he uses `modal-window.min.js`

Comment: @user1400288: Why don't use jQuery UI ? This is a library and it is NOT complicated.

Comment: try `e.which` instead of `e.keyCode` see [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

Comment: Please provide me a solution if anybody have...

Comment: I found following errors on page  Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'corner'       jquery-workarounds.js:185  Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dispatchEvent'    prototype.js:5738

Answer (score 0):

Try it on Jquery Escape plugin ([See Samples](http://ben.ferit.im/))

```
$(document).escape(function() { 
 alert('ESC button pressed'); 
});
```